# Tick position on X axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I limit showing ticks on X axis in Highcharts? The last one is outter of X axis:
[image]

My source:

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    events: {
        load: function(event) {
        }
    },
    type: 'spline',
    animation: false
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
colors: [
    '#499878','black'
],
rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true
},






series: [{
    name: 'Temperature (°C)',
    type: 'spline',
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' °C'
    },
    yAxis: 0,
    color: '#89A54E',
    data: []

},{
    name: 'Wind speed (m/s)',
    type: 'spline',
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' m/s'
    },
    yAxis: 1,
    color: '#4572A7',
    data: []
},{
    name: 'Humidity (%)',
    type: 'spline',
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' %'
    },
    yAxis: 2,
    color: '#910000',
    data: []
},{
    name: 'Wind direction (°)',
    type: 'spline',
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' °'
    },
    yAxis: 3,
    color: '#000000',
    dashStyle: 'shortdot',
    data: []
}],



xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 10000,
    min: 0,
    max: 0
},



yAxis: [{
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#89A54E'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature',
        style: {
            color: '#89A54E'
        }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    opposite: true
},{
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value +' m/s';
        },
        style: {
            color: '#4572A7'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Wind speed',
        style: {
            color: '#4572A7'
        }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    opposite: false,
    min: 0
},{
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value +' %';
        },
        style: {
            color: '#910000'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Humidity',
        style: {
            color: '#910000'
        }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    opposite: true
},{
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value +' °';
        },
        style: {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Wind direction',
        style: {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    },
    opposite: false,
    reversed: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,

    minorGridLineDashStyle: 'longdash',
    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    minorTickWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 90
}],




plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        lineWidth: 3,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 5
            }
        },
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true
         }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: Is this the actual code or did you cut it down?  1.) You didn't provide any sample data that would reproduce the problem and 2.) why is your xaxis min/max set to 0?  When asking questions on SO it is considered polite to provide a minimal code example that'll reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is the sens of using min and max as 0? Please provide full code, or replicate in jsfiddle.net, becuase defaulty it is not possible to achive this kind of chart.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's matter of `oveflow: 'justify'`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-overflow/)

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you use 'spacingRight' (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingRight) as below:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    events: {
        load: function(event) {
        }
    },
    type: 'spline',
    animation: false,
    spacingRight: 100 // you may change this for testing...
},
```